# NPE when initialization of lambda function

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a BytecodeCacheService class which is desgined as singlton. During its initilization, the NPE exception is thrown out.

The code is shown below:

```
public class BytecodeCacheService {

    public final static class CachePlacer{
        public final static BytecodeCacheService _instance = new BytecodeCacheService();    
    }

    private static ICache _cacheInstance = null ;
    static{
        _cacheInstance = new GlobalCache();
        System.out.println("Init "+_cacheInstance);

    }


    private BytecodeCacheService(){
        _logger.debug("Start Bytecode Cache Service");
    }

public static BytecodeCacheService get(){
    return CachePlacer._instance;
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ICache cache = new GlobalCache();
        System.out.println(cache.toString());
    }
}

class GlobalCache implements ICache{

    private ConcurrentMap<IGraphNode, BytecodeResource> _map = new ConcurrentHashMap<IGraphNode, BytecodeResource>();

    //Customize below values via annotation (xml configurtion or others)
    private final int MAX_ENTITES = Config.CACHE_GLOBAL_CACHE_SIZE;  // The maximal entities allowed in the GlobalCache (This is in theory).
    private final float _ratio = Config.CACHE_GLOBAL_CACHE_RATIO;   // Each purge removes (1-_ratios)*entities. 

    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1,  new ThreadFactory(){
        final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(1);

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread thread  = new Thread();
            thread.setName("GLobalCache: purge "+count.getAndIncrement());
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        }

    });

    public GlobalCache(){
        System.out.println("init 1...");
   line 171: exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{      
            //@TODO the future developer can think up better purge policy. Here I only use a simple NON-STRICT Longest un-used first. 
//          if(_map.size() > MAX_ENTITES*_ratio){
//              int len = (int) (MAX_ENTITES*(1-_ratio));
//              while(len>0){
//                  IGraphNode longest = null;
//                  long max=-1;
//                  Iterator<IGraphNode> iter = _map.keySet().iterator();
//                  //It is NON-Strict because during iteration the BytecodeClass in global Cache might be updated. 
//                  while(iter.hasNext()){
//                      IGraphNode node = iter.next();
//                      BytecodeResource resource = _map.get(node);
//                      if(longest == null || max < resource.getLife()){
//                          longest = node;
//                          max = _map.get(longest).getLife();
//                      }
//                  }
//                  if(longest!=null)
//                      _map.remove(longest);
//              }
//              len--;
//          }
            System.out.println("Smile...");

        }, 1, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("init 2...");
    }
}
```

I tried something here:

1) Run the main method of BytecodeService, and it runs successfully. The result is:

```
init 1...
init 2...
Init code.jit.asm.services.GlobalCache@5518e919
init 1...
init 2...
code.jit.asm.services.GlobalCache@11ebb918
```

2), Run something BytecodeCacheService.get(), it reports:

```
init 1...
29/Mar/2016:16:19:03:347 -0300 [main] DEBUG c.j.a.services.BytecodeCacheService - Start Bytecode Cache Service
java.lang.invoke.ConstantObjectHandle
J9VMInternals.java:137:in `ensureError': java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    from J9VMInternals.java:126:in `recordInitializationFailure'
    from BytecodeGenerator.java:59:in `action'
    from BytecodeGenerator.java:333:in `run'
    from BytecodeGenerator.java:328:in `generate'
    from CallSite.java:137:in `jitMethodHandle'
    from MutableCallSite.java:61:in `<init>'
    from SwitchPoint.java:135:in `<init>'
    from FailoverSwitchPointInvalidator.java:34:in `<clinit>'
    from OptoFactory.java:72:in `newGlobalInvalidator'
    from Ruby.java:5047:in `<init>'
    from Ruby.java:329:in `newInstance'
    from Main.java:272:in `internalRun'
    from Main.java:231:in `run'
    from Main.java:200:in `main'
Caused by:

BytecodeCacheService.java:171:in `<init>': java.lang.NullPointerException
    from BytecodeCacheService.java:40:in `<clinit>'
    from BytecodeGenerator.java:59:in `action'
    from BytecodeGenerator.java:333:in `run'
    from BytecodeGenerator.java:328:in `generate'
    from CallSite.java:137:in `jitMethodHandle'
    from MutableCallSite.java:61:in `<init>'
    from SwitchPoint.java:135:in `<init>'
    from FailoverSwitchPointInvalidator.java:34:in `<clinit>'
    from OptoFactory.java:72:in `newGlobalInvalidator'
    from Ruby.java:5047:in `<init>'
    from Ruby.java:329:in `newInstance'
    from Main.java:272:in `internalRun'
    from Main.java:231:in `run'
    from Main.java:200:in `main'
```

The line 171 is the `exec.scheduleAtFixedRate({}->{}..)` in the class `GlobalCache`.  I debug it and exception is thrown in this method invocation.

Is there any wrong the way I use lambda function (I am new to this part currently)? Could anyone explain the different result between 1) and 2)? I use Java 8 and J9 JVM here.

Comment: Is your lambda working in the first case? I did not see "Smile" in any log. Plus exec.scheduleAtFixedRate is not a Collection so why iterating through it?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You are using lazy instantiation for `BytecodeCacheService`, but that instantiation is almost a no-op. The potentially expensive operation is the instantiation of `GlobalCache` which you perform non-lazily in the `static` initializer which will be executed *before* `get()` is invoked. Besides that, you should *never* start new threads in a constructor. Posting asynchronous actions in a constructor, even with a delay of one second, is a broken design.

Comment: Generally, if you have circular dependencies in the class initialization, you can get divergent behavior depending on how you trigger the initialization, but the code as you have posted has no such dependencies. So unless `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` returns `null` or either, the bytecode or the stack trace, has been manipulated, it’s impossible to get that specific exception with that code.